# scikit-learn LabelBinarizer - one hot vs. dummy coding

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dummy-variable, one-hot-encoding

There is a beautiful function in scikit-learn LabelBinarizer, which works as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
lb = LabelBinarizer(sparse_output = True)
lb.fit_transform(['green', 'yellow', 'blue'])
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 0 0]]
```

But I wonder, if I can get the following output from it or any
alternative function:

```
   [[0 0]
     [0 1]
     [1 0]]
```

I tried option `sparse_output = True`, but it is it not what I want.

Comment: No. You can either use `pandas.get_dummies(drop_first=True)` or drop the column from the output of LabelBinarizer yourself. But then you may face problems during inverse transform. Better to make a custom tranformer